# I'm trying to have my app pop viewControllers when it reaches 9:00 UTC time every day

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, server, nsdate

I'm trying have my app pop viewControllers when it reaches 9:00 UTC time every day. I don't want it to use local time as that can change in different regions, and can be altered. I thought of using a server time, but I'm having issues getting that solution to work. I got an epoch timestamp and converted it to a Date.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()   
let timestamp = FIRServerValue.timestamp()
  ref.setValue(timestamp)

    ref.observe(.value, with: {
        snap in
        if let t = snap.value as? TimeInterval {
            // Cast the value to an NSTimeInterval
            // and divide by 1000 to get seconds.
            print("this is the time in seconds \(t)")
            let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: t)
            print("this is the time \(Date(timeIntervalSince1970: t/1000))")
```

It prints out `this is the time 2016-10-10 18:40:21 +0000`.

The problem is figuring out how to get only the hour minutes and seconds out of this so I can compare the time dates.

Comment: Do you need help by getting the time or with the function that needs to hit the function at 9 o'clock?

Comment: A little of both in finding a cohesive solution. There are probably many ways I can do this, but some of the possible solutions I've thought of are pretty messy.

Comment: It's not quite clear how you're using Firebase in this context. Does this code run only once? It should run periodically. Then you should check the hour component by using the NSCalendar class and fire whatever you want if it reaches 9:00 o'clock (or a Firebase remote configuration value).

Comment: It runs every time when the viewLoads. I'm not quite sure how to check the difference between hour minutes and seconds, while not looking at the day, month or year. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Artem and his help, I was directed on the right path. After a lot of time spent researching date conversion, I figured this out. The final goal is to convert the two values into Integers so I can compare them in seconds and use them in a timer to figure out how much time is remaining.

```
  ref.observe(.value, with: {
        snap in
        if let t = snap.value as? TimeInterval {

     let FinalTimeInterval = self.convertStringToDateToIntStartTime() - self.convertEpochTimeStampToDateToStringToDateToIntEndTime(timeInterval: t)

            if FinalTimeInterval < 0 {
                print("less than zero")
            } else {

            let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(FinalTimeInterval), repeats: false) { _ in
                // TODO: pop view controllers
                print("i'm so happy this is working")
            }
RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)

            }

        }
    })


  func convertEpochTimeStampToDateToStringToDateToIntEndTime(timeInterval: TimeInterval) -> Int {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval/1000)

    var dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    let dateString = dateFormater.string(from: date)

    let endTime = dateFormater.date(from: dateString)


        dateFormater.dateFormat = "HH"
        let endHours = Int(dateFormater.string(from: endTime!))
        dateFormater.dateFormat = "mm"
        let endMinutes = Int(dateFormater.string(from: endTime!))
        dateFormater.dateFormat = "ss"
        let endSeconds = Int(dateFormater.string(from: endTime!))



    return endSeconds! + endMinutes! * 60 + endHours! * 3600


}
func convertStringToDateToIntStartTime() -> Int {

    var dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

    let startTime = dateFormater.date(from: "09:00:00")
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "HH"

    let startHours = Int(dateFormater.string(from: startTime!))
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "mm"

    let startMinutes = Int(dateFormater.string(from: startTime!))
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "ss"

    let startSeconds = Int(dateFormater.string(from: startTime!))



    return startSeconds! + startMinutes! * 60 + startHours! * 3600

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of options might be:

- To request a current time from the server on the start of the app.
- Calculate a difference between 9:00 UTC and the current time.
- Set a timer (`NSTimer`) which fires when the difference has passed.
- And finally, handle the callback in any way you like: pop screens, show a popup, etc.

Comment: Ya I thought this would be a good option and tried the same thing. So I used firebase to get the current time as an epoch timestamp and converted it. I'll edit my question to reflect what i've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.hour = 9

let nineOClock = calendar.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: components as DateComponents, matchingPolicy: .strict)

let timer = Timer(fireAt: nineOClock!, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(doSomething), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)

func doSomething(){
    print("Doing something")
}
```

Comment: As far as I anderstood device time is not an option.

Comment: Ya I like this option but unfortunately if the user were to change the time, I don't think this would work. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A method which calculates time (in seconds) until the next 9 am based on the current time (seconds from 1970).

```
func untilNineAmSeconds(now: Int) -> Int {

    let todaySeconds = now % 86400
    let hourSeconds = 3600
    let nineAmSeconds = 9 * hourSeconds
    let daySeconds = 24 * hourSeconds

    if todaySeconds < nineAmSeconds {
        return nineAmSeconds - todaySeconds
    } else {
        return (daySeconds - todaySeconds) + nineAmSeconds
    }
}
```

Now you (1) request a current time from Firebase, (2) get a time interval before 9 am, and (3) schedule a timer.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()   
let timestamp = FIRServerValue.timestamp()
ref.setValue(timestamp)

ref.observe(.value, with: { snap in
    guard let ts = snap.value as? TimeInterval else {
        return
    }

    let seconds = untilNineAmSeconds(now: Int(ts))

    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(seconds), repeats: false) { _ in
        // TODO: pop view controllers
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I like the solution but i'm getting a few errors. I'm getting an error with the guard statement and with the Int(timeInterval).  There is no timeInterval, where are u getting it from? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: So i'm not sure if the function works like it is supposed to. When I use it, and print out seconds, I keep getting very random results. I'll get like 80887, then i'll run the app 10 seconds later and get 72708. I tried going though the function last night and it it seems like the else statement "return (daySeconds - todaySeconds) + nineAmSeconds" is getting called. So it's supposed to take 86400 seconds - time epoch + 9 o'clock or whatever time in seconds. Would that not be a negative number? But regardless, not getting my desired results. Any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also not sure milliseconds is accounted for which is why I keep getting varied results.

Comment: I figured out a solution. I want to up vote your answer for all your help, but in the end, it didn't work for me. Sorry, but thank you again. In my answer I will mention all of your help.